# Call MPMoviePlayerViewController done button. iPad

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

When the user gets out of the app or changes apps while a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is being displayed, then they get back in to the app the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is still there for about a half of a second.  I want to either keep the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` up, or have it out of the way before the user can see it when they re-open the app, or just dismiss the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` right before the user gets out of the app.  Right now I plan to dismiss the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in my AppDelegate just before the user leaves the app.

So I want to know if it is possible to call the done button on the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, and I want to do this from my AppDelegate

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPMoviePlayer done button issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142571/mpmovieplayer-done-button-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification` `NSNotificationCenter`. Below is good

discussion on this topic may it helps you:

[Done button event MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227801/done-button-event-mpmovieplayercontroller)