# Modal MPMoviePlayerViewController dismissing with a wrong animation

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm currently having trouble with a MPMoviePlayerViewController.

```
- (void)playVideo:(UIButton *)sender {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.howToVideoURL];
    [self presentModalViewController:mp animated:YES];
}
```

From that point on, the player is presented modally, plays the video and everything is nice.
Except when I hit the "Done" button.

Instead of dismissing the modal in the usual way (i.e. by lowering the screen until it disappears, uncovering the previous screen), it looks like the previous screen is presented modally on top of the player. There is no specific code on my to dismiss the modal, I rely on the native "Done" button.

Has anyone experienced this earlier? How can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227801/done-button-event-mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated`?